# Error setting TTL index on collection

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, mlab, keystonejs

I'm getting the following issue using KeystoneJs v3.

Hosted on Azure, with a MongoLab hosting the database.  I don't get this error whilst accessing the db via KeystoneJs on localhost

I'm pretty fresh to KeystoneJs, node and mongo, so apologies if this has been asked and solved many times before.

```
Thu Feb 19 2015 21:23:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Unaught exception: Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : app_sessions
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:169:23
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1482:46
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1615:20
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:169:22
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:700:39
    at Cursor.close (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:989:5)
    at Cursor.wrappedCursorClose [as close] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\mongodb.js:226:20)
    at commandHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:700:21)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1888:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:453:41)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:487:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:445:20)
    at emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:201:13)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
```

Comment: The callstack alone isn't too helpful. make sure you understand the requirements of TTL indexes - is it part of a compound index? Is the data stored as date? (`ISODate` in the mongo console)? See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/#considerations

Comment: Cheers, but you might as well be speaking in swahili. :) Very new to MongoDb. Hopefully some people with experience of KeystoneJs can help me out.

Comment: Well, a TTL index only makes sense on values that are dates. Also, there are some limitations to TTL indexes when combined with other advanced features. It might help if you post the source code that's calling the create index method.

Comment: Sounds very similar to: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/688, although that should have been fixed well before Keystone 0.3. What version of connect-mongo are you using? What does your session store config look like?

Comment: I forked the [SydJs](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site/) a while back. so i'm still on mongo-connect 0.4.x. I'll upgrade and see if that fixes the issue. Cheers

Comment: Upgraded to connect-mongo 0.70, same issue

Comment: Where in KeystoneJs would i find the session store config?

Comment: @MrBliz look around here https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/40563de928892deb9f707a4498439663d154443d/lib/core/mount.js#L124